I need help Integration Email in Bitrix24 On Premise
I am attempting to integrate Google Workspace Gmail with Bitrix24 On-Premise, but the integration has failed. I need assistance to set up the integration so that sending and receiving emails can function properly.
I have followed the default articles provided by Bitrix and attempted to configure the SMTP settings, but I was still unable to complete the integration successfully.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
